# How do I insert into a table with a frozen type with the Java driver?

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to write a query to insert data in the table "users". How do I write the query to insert into users? And how do i write the code in Java

```
CREATE TYPE address (
         street text,
         city text,
         zip int
     );

CREATE TABLE users (
     login text PRIMARY KEY,
     first_name text,
     last_name text,
     email text,
     addresses map<text, address>
 );
```

And how do I write the code below correctly in java?

```
public void insertHotels(String login, String first_name, String last_name, String email, addresses) {
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints(serverIP)
                .build();

        try (Session session = cluster.connect("hotel_db")) {
String insert_query = "INSERT INTO users (login, first_name, last_name, email, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
PreparedStatement pStatement = session.prepare(insert_query);
BoundStatement bStatement = pStatement.bind(login, first_name, last_name, email, address);

            session.execute(bStatement);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using [`4.15.0` version of Java driver](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.datastax.oss/java-driver-core/4.15.0/bundle) here. I'm using [DataStax Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/astra) for my demonstration.

The table looks like,

```
CREATE TABLE payloadtest.users (
    login text PRIMARY KEY,
    addresses map<text, frozen<address>>,
    email text,
    first_name text,
    last_name text
)...;
```

Your code will look like,

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.BoundStatement;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.PreparedStatement;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.data.UdtValue;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.UserDefinedType;

public class UdtValueExample {
    private static final String KEYSPACE = "payloadtest";
    private static final String UDT_ADDRESSES = "addresses";
    public static void main(String... args) {
        // Create the CqlSession object:
           try (CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder()
               .withCloudSecureConnectBundle(Paths.get("./src/main/resources/secure-connect-payloadtest.zip"))
               //Org Admin Role
               .withAuthCredentials("CHANGE_ME", "AstraCS:CHANGE_ME")
               .build()) {
               PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare("INSERT INTO payloadtest.users(login,first_name,last_name,email,addresses) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
               
               // User define type
               UserDefinedType addressesUdt = session.getMetadata()
                    .getKeyspace(KEYSPACE)
                    .flatMap(ks -> ks.getUserDefinedType("address"))
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Missing UDT definition"));
               
               UdtValue addressUdtValue = addressesUdt.newValue("some_street", "some_city", 12345);
               Map<String, UdtValue> addressesMap = new HashMap<>();
               addressesMap.put("key1", addressUdtValue);
               BoundStatement bs =
                        ps.boundStatementBuilder()
                            .setString("login", "some_login")
                            .setString("email", "some@email.com")
                            .setString("first_name", "first")
                            .setString("last_name", "last")
                            .setMap(UDT_ADDRESSES, addressesMap, String.class, UdtValue.class)
                            .build();
                    session.execute(bs);
           }
           System.out.println("COMPLETED");
    }

}
```

and results would look like,

```
token@cqlsh:payloadtest> select * from users;

 login      | addresses                                                        | email          | first_name | last_name
------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------------+-----------
 some_login | {'key1': {street: 'some_street', city: 'some_city', zip: 12345}} | some@email.com |      first |      last

(1 rows)
```

Read References:

- [Documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/udts/)
- [Example repo](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/java-cassandra-driver-from3x-to4x/blob/master/example-4x/src/main/java/com/datastax/samples/SampleCode4x_CRUD_04_ListSetMapAndUdt.java)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 

I'm using java version 15.0.1 and I am using Intellij and Docker. DataStax seems a bit too mush for me, since I just want to know how to deal with the "frozen"-part. Is it a HashMap?

Comment: I'm not really sure what is `15.0.1` is because there is only [up to the `4.15.0` version of the DataStax Java Driver (g:com.datastax.oss & a:java-driver-core)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.oss/java-driver-core). Could it be that you're using a different driver? If so, post the complete groupId and artifactId with version that you're using. Also, you could check the CQL to Java mappings [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/#cql-to-java-type-mapping). Read about [frozen](https://www.baeldung.com/cassandra-frozen-keyword) for more info.

Comment: @Mewken, Madhavan is talking about the version of the Cassandra Java driver whereas you're talking about the Java JDK/JRE version. 

Comment: Oh, yeah you're right. It's Java version `15.0.1`. Thanks @ErickRamirez! This codebase should work with that version too.

Comment: Ahh, I see hehe :D Thank you guys. I haven't had time to look this up until now. I will write again as soon as i've tried this.